# Postfix TLS with Letsencrypt configuration

Tags: ssl, postfix, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am running Postfix inside a docker container. Certificate are generated with certbot.

With the following configuration:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/var/keys/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/var/keys/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

Every attempt to send an email to Gmail ends up with:

```
status=deferred (TLS is required but was not offered by host alt1.aspmx.l.google.co
```

When I change `smtp_tls_security_level` to `may`, emails are going out; however, without TLS, it doesn't solve the issue at all.

When I do an openssl tls check, everything seems to be fine; it is not attaching it to emails.

Does anyone have idea what am I doing wrong?

Log after disabling ipv6and adding debug_peer_list:

```
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/cleanup[489]: 2910E1667CE: message-id=<152ab11ab7027719630ac639f395ba9a@swift.generated>
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/qmgr[481]: 2910E1667CE: from=<acc@service.example.net>, size=6181, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: initializing the client-side TLS engine
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtpd[485]: disconnect from ec2-54-154-126-37.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com[54.154.126.37]
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: enabling PIX workarounds: disable_esmtp delay_dotcrlf for aspmx.l.google.com[66.102.1.26]:25
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: TLS is required, but was not offered by host aspmx.l.google.com[66.102.1.26]
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: enabling PIX workarounds: disable_esmtp delay_dotcrlf for alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[142.250.153.27]:25
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: TLS is required, but was not offered by host alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[142.250.153.27]
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: enabling PIX workarounds: disable_esmtp delay_dotcrlf for alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[142.251.9.27]:25
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: TLS is required, but was not offered by host alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[142.251.9.27]
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: < aspmx3.googlemail.com[142.251.9.27]:25: 220 ********************************************************************************
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: name_mask: disable_esmtp
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: name_mask: delay_dotcrlf
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: enabling PIX workarounds: disable_esmtp delay_dotcrlf for aspmx3.googlemail.com[142.251.9.27]:25
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: > aspmx3.googlemail.com[142.251.9.27]:25: HELO mail.example.net
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: < aspmx3.googlemail.com[142.251.9.27]:25: 250 mx.google.com at your service
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: server features: 0x30000 size 0
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: TLS is required, but was not offered by host aspmx3.googlemail.com[142.251.9.27]
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: > aspmx3.googlemail.com[142.251.9.27]:25: QUIT
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: name_mask: resource
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: name_mask: software
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: enabling PIX workarounds: disable_esmtp delay_dotcrlf for aspmx2.googlemail.com[142.250.153.27]:25
Feb  8 10:50:24 92d95fdf2397 postfix/smtp[490]: 2910E1667CE: to=<kamil+bdosr@example.com>, relay=aspmx2.googlemail.com[142.250.153.27]:25, delay=0.37, delays=0.05/0.01/0.31/0, dsn=4.7.4, status=deferred (TLS is required, but was not offered by host aspmx2.googlemail.com[142.250.153.27])
```

Comment: Do you have any firewalls between the sending host and the Gmail servers? `telnet alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 25` and check the output for STARTTLS.

Comment: It does output STARTTLS:
`EHLO localhost
250-mx.google.com at your service, [myip]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-XXXXXXXA
250 XXXXXXXB`

Comment: https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_loglevel

Comment: More logs like:
Feb  7 16:02:05 a544bd58a6b0 postfix/smtp[1512]: DA5181667CF: TLS is required, but was not offered by host aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]
Feb  7 16:02:05 a544bd58a6b0 postfix/smtp[1512]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c02::1a]:25: Cannot assign requested address
Feb  7 16:02:05 a544bd58a6b0 postfix/smtp[1512]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4025:c03::1a]:25: Cannot assign requested address
Feb  7 16:02:05 a544bd58a6b0 postfix/smtp[1512]: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c16::1b]:25: Cannot assign requested address

Comment: Please add the logs to the question, they are unreadable in the comments.

Comment: Also, you have broken IPv6, disable it for postfix. https://serverfault.com/questions/933206/postfix-cannot-assign-requested-address

Comment: You could add `debug_peer_list = /etc/postfix/debug_peers` and then list the problematic hosts in that file to get more detailed logs on why the TLS failed.

Comment: I have added logs into topic description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `smtp_pix_workarounds=delay_dotcrlf`. The default setting for [smtp_pix_workarounds](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_pix_workarounds)  includes `disable_esmtp` which disables `EHLO` so your SMTP client won't receive `STARTTLS` response.

Answer (score 0):

Having smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt means that you require client cert validation so best practice is to leave it on may

```
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_auth_only = yes
# Enable Opportunistic TLS
smtp_tls_security_level = may
    smtp_tls_cert_file=/var/keys/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_key_file=/var/keys/privkey.pem
```

The smtpd are for incoming connections
https://blog.matrixpost.net/enable-tls-for-postfix-on-ubuntu/

Comment: If I change it to may it works fine, unless the end server requires TLS - then I am getting error message `Recipient organization requires TLS`.

Comment: There are not many mailserver yet rhat require tls i think, if you set it encrypt i think your whole mail flow would break/stop. There might be another issue. May means to allow non-TLS connections but prefer TLS.